# How can i add custom field inside custom post taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I need to add one image uploading field to my custom post type. But it should be inside the taxonomy (product category). How can i add that field?.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wlg_cstm_register');  

 function wlg_cstm_register() {  

    $product_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Products', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Product'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Product'),
    'new_item' => __('New Product'),
    'view_item' => __('View Products'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Products'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Products found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Products found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

    $product_args = array(  
         'labels' => $product_labels,  
         'public' => true,  
         'show_ui' => true,  
         'capability_type' => 'post',  
         'hierarchical' => false,  
         'rewrite' => true,
         'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/resources/img/Products-icon.png',  // Icon Path
        'has_archive' => false       
        );

     register_post_type( 'products' , $product_args ); 
     register_taxonomy( 'item', 'products', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => __('Product Category'), 'query_var' => 'item' ) );
 }
```

Comment: Please always add your code to your question. Do not link to outside sources for relevant parts of a question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/

OR

Adding custom meta fields to a taxonomy requires three separate functions: one to add the field to the Add New page; one to add the field to the Edit Term page; and one to save the values of the custom field from both pages.

You can also do this by code yourself like this :

https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/